# Moving legend in ggplot geom_line is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to move the legend in my ggplot but general commands like `guides`and `legend.position` are not working.

This is my code:

```
sum_CH$`Biogeographic Regions`<-factor(sum_CH$`Biogeographic Regions`, levels=c("Jura", "Midland", "North", "East", "South", "West","Swiss"), #changing legend order
                  labels=c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                           "5", "6", "7"))         #changing legend names


require(ggplot2)


p2<-ggplot(data=sum_CH, aes(x=sum_CH$Day, y=sum_CH$value, group=`Biogeographic Regions`))+geom_line(aes(linetype=`Biogeographic Regions`, color=`Biogeographic Regions`), size=1.1)+
    xlab("")+
    ylab(expression(atop(paste("%"))))+
    ggtitle(expression(atop(paste("XXXX"), paste("XX"))))+
    scale_x_discrete(sum_CH$Month, breaks=c(15, 45, 75, 105, 135, 165, 195, 225, 255, 285, 315, 345), labels=month.abb)+    #adding months to x axis
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#FFCCCC", "#8ACC66", "#C7EEFC", "#00A9E6", "#BED2FF", "#0070FF", "Black"))+   #changing line color
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c (1,1,1,1,1,1,4))+      #changing line type
    geom_vline(xintercept=c(150,270), colour="grey", linetype="longdash")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=rel(1)))+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1)))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, color="black"))+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=13,color="black"))+
    theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the code concerning moving the legend? Be aware that every time you call `theme_xxx()` it will overwrite all previous `theme()` calls.

Comment: ahh, I deleted what I already experimented about moving the legend and show you simply my code. thanks for the advice about `theme`

Comment: `theme(legend.position = "top") +` isn't working?

Comment: Perfect. When following the hint of mtoto by combining all `theme()`and adding `legend.position="top"`it worked out fine. Thanks a lot for your advices!!!

Comment: Side note: do not use `$` inside of `aes()` as in `aes(x=sum_CH$Day, y=sum_CH$value,...)`. The whole reason you specified `data = sum_CH` was so that `ggplot()` would look in that data frame for columns. Using `$` to select columns in `aes()` is both unnecessary and very likely to break things in unexpected ways down the road.